# Which design is better? Put this logic in frontend or backend?

Tags: oop

We have an API called `copy(fileName)`, basically it copies file from source to target and since source and target are in the same place, so we don't need to specify it.

Now we are splitting the file system into different locations, say `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`. We are always copying to `D`, but the file could from `A`, `B`, or `C`. So we need some logic like:

```
function checkAndCopy(fileName) {
    if (fileExistInA) copy from A to D
    else if (fileExistInB) copy from B to D
    else if (fileExistInC) copy from C to D
}
```

I feel like to place this function in backend The reason is the backend change should be encapsulated within the API so the caller doesn't need to worry about the implementation details.

However our backend team doesn't want to maintain it, they only want to provide a final version of copyFrom(fileName, source). so I suggest them to have source as optional param or empty string if front end don't know the source. Once we make the frontend change, we will always send source and remove the empty string/optional param logic from copyFrom(fileName, source).

Backend people think using optional param or deliberately pass empty string is a bad design, don't want it even they know this is temporary.

So which is the better design?

1. put this logic in backend, either having one API copy(fileName, source) and pass source as optional param/empty string or have 2 separate functions such as copyFrom(fileName, source) and checkAndCopy(fileName);
2. create a new function checkAndCopy in frontend, and another new function copy(fileName, source) in backend and let frontend decide which one to call.

Please note my question is not about how to write the functions, but where to put these functions.

Comment: To clarify, if the source is an empty string... You would have logic that would just copy nothing over?

Comment: I just updated my question, hopefully it's clear now. So if the source is an empty string, we will check from A, B, C to find the file, and if we find the file in A, then copy from A.

There's no argument in this logic, the difference is where to put this logic, within the backend API or make a new API in frontend to call it when source is unkown.

Comment: I see, did you check out @jdickel's answer? I'm not sure if there's a difference between makinga  frontend or backend API, sorry.

Comment: no worries, yeah, the reason I want to put it in backend is because frontend shouldn't care about the implementation details.

Comment: That makes sense, API is usually with backend.

Answer (score 2):

You should just have the atomic call like  `copy(source, target)` in the API.
The copy function itself should not be related to a specific directory. It’s use case is to copy, not to determine the target directory.

Comment: I actually care more about this logic should be in backend or frontend. I'm okay with having a separate function for this but strongly disagree to have this logic in frontend since this is backend logic.

I've updated my question so it's less misleading.

Comment: It‘s definately a backend function. But not inside the copy! You should have two calls in the frontend like „getSourcefolderForFile(filename)“ and then send the result to ‚copy(source, target)‘.

Comment: Eventually we will send source from frontend and call copyFrom(fileName, source), but this is a temporary solution before the frontend change. That's why I suggested to have this empty string logic within the function, once the front end change is ready, we can just remove it.